.safeAreaInsets on ScrollView blocks touches in SwiftUI on iOS17
I am trying to add safe area to a ScrollView, but noticed that on iOS17 I am unable to tap any content inside the safe area of the ScrollView.
Example code:
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { i in
            Button("Button \(i)") { print("tapped \(i)" ) }
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
.safeAreaInset(edge: .top, content: {
    Spacer().frame(width: 0, height: 500)
})

Running this on iOS17, scrolling the buttons up into the safe area will make them not tappable.
Is there any solution for this problem on iOS17 besides using a ZStack or overlay? Both of that is not an option in my case since my main goal is to move the refresh indicator of the ScrollView, which (as far as I'm aware) can only be achieved via safe area.

Why do you want to move the refresh indicator? That's a rather weird thing to want to move.

I don't think the exact requirements are super-relevant to the question but the short story is I'm building a collapsable header (that shrinks while scrolling) and that header sits on top of the scrollview as an overlay, and I want to move the refresh indicator below that header.

The header shouldn't be an overlay. Put the header in the safeAreaInset, then you would't have this problem.

Yes on paper I agree, in practice changing the safe area during scroll unfortunately causes a number of problems. It influences the scroll behaviour, the behaviour of ScrollBehaviours and actually doesn't solve the issue – for whatever reason in my testing the initially set top safe area remained untappable. But I agree this should be the correct solution. In the end I had to settle for a custom pull-to-refresh indicator on iOS17 and below – which brings its own set of issues but that's not relevant to this question.

Would you be okay using a List? That way they do remain tappable for whatever reason. And you can modify the list style properties pretty well with just SwiftUI nowadays.
List(0..<100, id: \.self) { i in
        Button("Button \(i)") { print("tapped \(i)" ) }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .refreshable {
        print("refreshing")
    }
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .top, content: {
        Rectangle().frame(width: 0, height: 500)
    })

Or if the refresh indicator being in a different place is all you need, you can just put one wherever with the default ProgressView(). Something like,
if refreshing {
   ProgressView()
}


Interesting that it works on a List, I suppose it's just an oversight from Apple on ScrollView. Unfortunately in my case it's not really an option since I built a reusable component that doesn't necessarily always contain List data.
The idea of just showing another ProgressView is actually pretty clever and might be the best solution here. It has some downsides (e.g. the user will not receive feedback while pulling down like with Apple's indicator) but this might be fixable with some additional code.
